# TypeError: input expected 1 argument at most got 4

Tags: python

making a random one digit number addition problem generator and i ended up with this error

```
import random 

num = random.randint(0,9)
bothnumbers = []
score = 0

for i in range (10):
  q = bothnumbers.append(int(input("What is the answer to: " ,num,"+",num )))
  answer = sum(bothnumbers)
  if q == answer:
      score=+1

print("Your score is: ",score)
```

Comment: [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) only takes _one_ argument, the string to print as a prompt.  `"What is the answer to: " ,num,"+",num` is 4 arguments.

Comment: `input` isn't as flexible as `print`. You have to pass it a single string for the prompt.

Comment: Include the traceback so we know which line failed. Also, consider boiling this down to a small script that just demonstrates the problem. In your case, a single line demo of the `input` statement would do it.

Answer (score 3):

`input` accepts a single string so instead of

```
input("What is the answer to: " ,num,"+",num )
```

You could do

```
input(f"What is the answer to: {num} + {num}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`bothnumbers.append` returns nothing, so `q` is going to be `None`.  I don't know what you're trying to do with `bothnumbers`.  You never compute `num+num`, so you have no way of checking the answer.  And your test is always going to ask the same question every time.  And you never initialized `score`.

I think you want this:

```
import random
score = 0
for _ in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(0,9)
    num2 = random.randint(0,9)
    q = int(input(f"What is the answer to {num1}+{num2}? " ))
    if q == num1+num2:
        score += 1

print( f"Your score was {score}")
```